# Can one obtain access tokens for Azure AD to call GraphAPI without an 'application' (client ID)?

Tags: .net-core, azure-active-directory, azure-ad-graph-api

I am trying to create a console app with .NET Core to manipulate Azure AD resources via GraphAPI. I want to obtain an access token interactively - PublicClientApplicationBuilder...Build().AcquireTokenInteractive(...) takes care of opening a browser and conducting the OAuth2 flow.

If the signed-in user can already carry out changes in Azure AD, using the Azure portal say, then do I need to set up an app registration for this at all? Or is it required to set one up with the required permissions and make it issue a delegated-permission access token to the signed-in user?

This would be a corporate (intranet) application.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Under normal circumstances you always need an application registration to call any Graph APIs. Per the documentation:

> Before your app can get a token from the Microsoft identity platform,
> it must be registered in the Azure portal. Registration integrates
> your app with the Microsoft identity platform and establishes the
> information that it uses to get tokens...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/auth/auth-concepts

This is a security mechanism, and a darned good one. This helps ensure that malicious applications (viruses etc.) can't be downloaded to machines with cached AAD credentials and start doing damage to the AD tenant.

Now, putting on the rebel hat here for a second, you might legitimately be thinking, there are downloadable Microsoft applications that can do this without special registration in the tenant's AD. There's the Azure CLI of course, and Storage Explorer, to name two. Why can't you just do what they do? I don't know for sure, but my strong suspicion is that there are mechanisms to make it very difficult to impersonate these applications to work without app registration, but probably not impossible (in other words, presumably very good obfuscation, but theoretically breakable). Doing so would probably put you in DMCA-land, though, and in any event, wouldn't be looked kindly upon by security professionals.

You asked about the Azure Portal and stored credentials there. Of course that's a web app, and those credentials would therefore be stored in browser storage. Is it theoretically possible for your console app to get to them and use them? If you have access to the user's disk drive, then sure, anything's possible. But again, we are talking about gray (at best) hat tactics here rather than accepted practices.

So if you're making a legitimate application that you want your customers' security teams to be willing to allow to be used, you would need to go through the app registration process, be assigned permissions, and use the application ID in all your API calls.

Comment: Makes sense. My suspicion re. Azure portal, Azure CLI etc is that they in fact do have their own 'invisible', well-known special case app registrations. Like '00000003-0000-0000-c000-000000000000' being MS Graph API, for instance.

Comment: Oh yes for sure, the application ID is easy to get, but - and I'm in total speculation land now - there is probably something like a private key for signing nonce's and such that's embedded somewhere deeply, and that's what Graph would actually use to verify the client's integrity. So probably possible to hack, but dark arts you probably don't want to be getting yourself involved with. :)

Comment: This has the very low level info - https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/v2-oauth2-client-creds-grant-flow. There's always an application ID, but there's also either a client secret or an assertion that's signed with a trusted asymmetric key. So one of those two things (the client secret or the key) is probably embedded in Azure-CLI and/or Storage Explorer. And frankly any standalone desktop app would have the same issue, which is why I personally would never make an app that called Graph APIs from the client's machine directly, but that's just me.

Comment: Yes. Far easier just to play the game with an app reg if that's the way it's played. Trying to bodge something homespun will backfire eventually, especially security-wise.